# Running a Dnx Console App with Project Dependencies as Global Command

Tags: c#, asp.net, dnx, dnu

I have a DNX console application that references a class library project. I am trying to publish this and install it as a global command.

I am doing this on Windows 10 OS.
[image: Projects Tree]

Console Project `Program.cs`

```
namespace Vert.Commands
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new ConsoleWriter();
            test.Talk("Test", ConsoleColor.Cyan);
        }
    }
}
```

Console Project `project.json`

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "Test App",
  "authors": [ "vrybak" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "CommandLib": "1.0.0-*"
  },
  "commands": {
    "vm-test-job": "Vert.Commands"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {}
  }
}
```

Class Library: `CommandLib` file: `ConsoleWriter`

```
namespace CommandLib
{
    public class ConsoleWriter
    {
        public void Talk(string message, ConsoleColor color)
        {
            var currentColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
            Console.ForegroundColor = color;
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            Console.ForegroundColor = currentColor;
        }
    }
}
```

Class Library: `project.json`

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "CommandLib Class Library",
  "authors": [ "vrybak" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
  }
}
```

I am trying to install a global command `vm-test-job`
To do this I

1. cd into the `src/Vert.Commands` folder
2. publish it as a package
3. `dnu publish --no-source -o artifacts\publish`
4. cd `\artifacts\publish\approot`
5. `dnu commands install .\packages\Vert.Commands\Vert.Commands.1.0.0.nupkg`

When I try to run my command `vm-test-job` I get an error

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CommandLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

How do I install a command that is in a console app project that references other projects?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please could you specify OS (I guess it's Windows), framework version you use. Thank you.

Comment: Did you specify dependencies as specified here : http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/projects.html#adding-dependencies

Comment: I did specify my dependencies, take a look at them in my project.json file

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing a...

```
dnu restore
```

...before installing the command ? I think dnvm needs to rebuild/repack your dependencies prior to install.

Take a look at this link, which tries to achieve the same thing as you do I assume. 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sujitdmello/archive/2015/04/23/step-by-step-installation-instructions-for-getting-dnx-on-your-laptop.aspx

Comment: I have tried doing the restore before as well. It would not let me publish it if the dependent packages were not there. The problem is that when I try to install a global command, dnx doesn't know where find the project references.